# Why the analyzation of code isn't right?

Tags: c

Why the output is "0  -6" and not "4 60"? Isn't k=8, l=2?

```
#define MAC(a,b) (a<b ? a*b:a-b)
void main (void)
{
   int i=2;
   int j=4;
   int k=MAC(i,j);
   int l=MAC(j,i);
   i=MAC(k+l,k-l);
   j=MAC(k-l,k+l);
   printf("%d %d\n", i,j);
}
```

Comment: do print statement after each line. learn to debug your own code =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One immediate problem. The expression

```
MAC(k+l,k-l)
```

becomes

```
(k+l<k-l ? k+l*k-l:k+l-k-l)
           ^^^^^^^
```

and, as you can see from the underlined bit, the expression is not what you think it is due to the precedence rules (multiplication is done before addition).

This can be fixed by ensuring each argument in the macro is parenthesised:

```
#define MAC(a,b) ((a)<(b) ? (a)*(b):(a)-(b))
```

but that still won't help if you pass in something like `n++` as it will be incremented multiple times.

Macros are very simple text substitutions and are well known to cause problems such as what you're seeing. My advice would be to turn `MAC` into a proper function that will avoid the problem completely, something like:

```
int mac (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return a * b;
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: ...and since it's likely to get inlined by the compiler, the resulting code may even be almost the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MAC(a,b) (a<b ? a*b:a-b)
void main (void)
{
   int i=2;
   int j=4;
   int k= i<j ? i*j:i-j;
   int l= j<i ? j*i:j-i;
   i= k+l<k-l ? k+l*k-l:k+l-k-l;
   j= k-l<k+l ? k-l*k+l:k-l-k+l;
   printf("%d %d\n", i,j);
}
```

This is what was produced after your code got preprocessed. preprocess macro happens before compilation. unlike compilation, there is no symbolic linking of variables that have occurred, but a mere 1 to 1 replacement of what you have defined.